# In classic ASP is it possible to create an END sub or function?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I created a class in asp and wanted to know if it was possible to create a function or sub named "END".  Is this possible even as a sub or function. The reason I wanted to call this for my class instance or class module like MyClass.End is to then call response.end?

Or is it possible to overide the response.end function to first check something before ending?

```
class Myclass

sub write(dim str)
      response.write(str)
end write

' Is this "END" possible?
sub end
   response.end
end sub

End class
```

Comment: why not using `Finish` instead, as `end` is [a reserved word](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/java/visual%20j++%20unleashed/ch34.htm#SummaryofReservedWords)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Correction***
This is not a valid subroutine declare : `sub write(dim str)`
**Dim** statement cannot be used to declare parameters. You should use ***ByRef*** or ***ByVal***. Default is ByRef if not specified.
And `end write` should be `end sub`.
See instructions from MSDN : [Sub Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt223ahx)

***Trick***
When you need to use a reserved keyword for property or method name in the classes, you can declare it with brackets. Then you can call without brackets.
Here the example:

```vb
Class Myclass

    Sub Write(str)
        Response.Write str
    End Sub

    Sub [End] 'with brackets
       Response.End
    End Sub

End Class

Set o = New Myclass
    o.write "what's up?"
    o.end 'without brackets

Response.Write "..." 'this will not be printed
```

Comment: Thank you so very much :)  If I could I would give you like 500 points.

Comment: @RetroCoder It's my pleasure. I don't need more points. To help even more valuable :)

Answer (score 1):

`end` is a reserved word for vbscript (what classic ASP is based on) so no. This is a list of reserved words... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216528

Comment: the above  link to `support.microsoft.com/kb/216528` results in `Sorry, page not found`
found an archive of that link at https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/216528