# VBScript: How do I invoke a function which is defined with a vowel in the Dispatch Map

Tags: vbscript, mfc, ole-automation

I have following VBScript-Script that creates an Microsoft COM Object.

```
set foo = CreateObject("Bar.ProgId")
foo.Einfügen()
```

The implementation of that COM Object is in the Dynamic Link Library `Foo.dll` which is using the Microsoft Foundation Framework (MFC) and especially the mechanism of [Dispatch Maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x5d24z3.aspx).

The Dispatch Maps show like this

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(Foo, CCmdTarget)
[...]
DISP_FUNCTION(Foo, "Einfügen", Insert, VT_I2, VTS_NONE)
[...]
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```

So far so good. When I create such a COM-Object in a VBA-Environment for example in a Excel Application, the invocation of `foo.Einfügen` is successful. Other than in the VBScript-Script.

I recognized that [OLE Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) is applied in VBA as well as in VBScript. But when I run the VBScript-Script I got the error

> Error: unknow character; Code 8000A0408;
>   Source: Compile failure in Microsoft VBScript

First I thought that the encoding in the VBScript-Script is wrong because of the character `ü` but I verified that it is ANSI encoded. I also verified that the [Windows Code Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) on my system is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) the Western Latin Character Set.

If I change `Einfügen` to `Einfuegen` in the Dispatch Map I assert that the VBScript-Script is working.

So my question is, why the behavior of the invocation of `foo.Einfügen` is different in VBScript than in VBA? What is the reason for this behavior?

For me the workaround is that I append a second `DISP_FUNCTION` Entry in the Dispatch Map that dispatches `Einfuegen` to the function `Insert`. In the VBScript-Script I invoke `foo.Einfuegen` and in VBA still `foo.Einfügen`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming conventions.
Unlike its bigger brothers VBA and VB6, it's a syntax error in VBScript.
VBScript compiler expects single-byte characters for expressions.

Have a look at:

[Syntax error (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/4cs3x452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Invalid character (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/324cbw04%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You have to write expressions containing unsupported characters enclosed in brackets.

```
set foo = CreateObject("Bar.ProgId")
foo.[Einfügen]() 'this will work
```

Comment: Awesome, I was interested in this question great answer!

Comment: Lankymart using brackets is also useful with `reserved words`. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8887247/893670

Comment: FYI: the 'Syntax error (VBScript)'nand 'Invalid character (VBScript)' links above are 404 - Page not found now :-(